# How can I specify an exact amount of spacing between children in a Jetpack Compose Column?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a Column in Jetpack Compose with a specific amount of spacing between each child element, such as 10.dp. In SwiftUI, this is relatively simple. I would just create a `VStack` with a `spacing` value:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let strings = ["Hello", "World", "Apples"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { string in
                Text(string).background(Color.green)
            }
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like in a SwiftUI Preview:

[image]

In Jetpack Compose, my code is:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ContentView() {
    val strings = listOf<String>("Hello", "World", "Apples")

    MaterialTheme {
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    // I would expect to be able to add something like ".spacer(10.dp)" here
            ) {
                strings.forEach { string ->
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green),
                        text = string
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    ContentView()
}
```

Because this code is missing any spacing, this is what it currently looks like:

[image]

My criteria are:

- A space of a specific height (such as 10.dp) should be present between child elements of a Column.
- The space should *not* appear before the *first* element.
- The space should *not* appear after the *last* element.

I would use a `Spacer` element, but I don't believe this would work, because in a for loop, I believe I would end up having a `Spacer` either before the first or after the last element, which I do not want.

Comment: You're looking for the [`verticalArrangement`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Column(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,kotlin.Function1)) parameter. You can pass in something like `Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)`. It's also possible to write your own custom `Arrangement` if you need something the system doesn't provide for you.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you @adneal!

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Use [Arrangement.spacedBy](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement#spacedBy(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)):

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Blue),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
) {
    // content here
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!!

Comment: any way of adding different spacing above child depending upon the child item ?

Comment: How to combine Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp) with Arrangement.Bottom?

Comment: @GeorgeShalvashvili use `.spacedBy(10.dp, Alignment.Bottom)`

Comment: Thank you very much for this valuable answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What if you also want to specify Center arrangement, like:
`verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center`
Is there a way to chain them?