# Cannot pass modifiers to columns in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, composable

I have this Composable, which is a [composable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial) function, and is meant to produce all the text for [this assignment](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems#1) on the Jetpack Compose course for Android Developers.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Article(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, textIds: Array<Int>, titleFontSize: TextUnit = 24.sp, ) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .then(modifier),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {
        textIds.toList().forEachIndexed { index, textId ->
            val stringValue: String = stringResource(id = textId)
            if (index == 0) {
                Text(
                    text = stringValue,
                    fontSize = titleFontSize
                )
            } else {
                Text(
                    text = stringValue
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

N.B: There is a seperate composable to render the header, if you were wondering

This code builds ok, but when I try and run it in the Emulator I get an error something like:

> Changes were not applied.
> Added variable(s) does not support value initialization: Adding static primitive com.example.articlestation.LiveLiterals$MainActivityKt.Int$$$this$call-$get-dp$$arg-0$call-padding$$this$call-then$arg-0$call-Column$fun-Article not known to be compile time constant

I can see that if I comment out the `verticalArrangement` and the `modifier` to the column everything runs fine, it seems to be a problem with running functions on the `Arrangement` or `Modifier` classes statically, but I see that in [other code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68200057/how-can-i-specify-an-exact-amount-of-spacing-between-children-in-a-jetpack-compo) that this is fine, how is my code different?

Comment: Is the function working properly when the line .then(modifier) is commented out? If yes, please include the code of how you called the Article function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to alter the modifier which is passed into the function parameter instead of using `then` keyword.

```
@Composable
fun Article(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textIds: Array<Int>,
    titleFontSize: TextUnit = 24.sp
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier // same as the function parameter
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {
        // You content goes here...
    }
}
```